# UIToolBar center.y returns value off the screen

Tags: ios, coordinates, uitoolbar

I'm doing a NSLog on the self.navigationController.toolbar.center.y of a UIToolBar that is visible.  I'm showing the UIToolBar in a UIViewController.

This (self.navigationController.toolbar.center.y) is returning 590 points (on retina 4inch simulator run).

This in my mental image is just under the visible screen:

- Retina 4inch is 568 points height
- 590 is 22 points greater (lower) than 568
- 22 points is half the default height of UIToolbar

I don't understand why this happens?

*Update*

Also should note I'm using [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:nil toolbarClass:[QuestionToolbar class] in this app to create a custom toolbar.

Comment: That's odd, I get 546 when I do this.

Comment: mmm. Well good that you're getting the 'right' result. I'll keep investigating. But I circumvented it and used the origin.y method which returns as 568, and the changed the logic based off this. So might be a while before I can come back and give any updates. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Hmmm... that number's not right either, it should be 524. But it does explain why your center.y is 590. It's like it thinks the bottom of the tool bar is the origin rather than the top..

Comment: This is a detail I should have included from the start, I'm using [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:nil toolbarClass:[QuestionToolbar class] approach to have a custom toolbar in the app.

Comment: Is the toolbar visible when the call is made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that at the time the call is made to get the coordinates of the toolbar, the toolbar *isn't visible yet*. Think about it. If the navigation controller keeps the toolbar just offscreen, then it's y origin would be 568 - the exact height of the screen.

Now add 22 to 568 and you get... 590. So, the toolbar is at the bottom of the screen. Try changing where/when you are checking the coordinates. Also, make sure the toolbar is actually visible :)

Comment: This was getting called on viewWillAppear

Comment: @drc Try it on `viewDidAppear`